# Spring data MongoDB: save subclass as superclass

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, inheritance, spring-data

Class B is a subclass of class A.

I have an object of class B. However, I only need to persist the fields of class A to MongoDB.

When I do the following with a Spring Data repository:

```
repository.save( (A) b )
```

This will nevertheless result in all fields of B being saved to MongoDB and the "_class" field being "B".

How can I achieve that the object of class B will be saved as object of class A to MongoDB?

**Edit: Background:**

The classes look like this:

```
class A {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String property;
    /* more properties, setters & getters */
}

class B extends A {
    private String additionalProperty;
    /* more properties, setters & getters */
}
```

I use class B only as a `@RequestParam` of a controller method, because it needs `additionalProperty` to process the request. Later, the program will solely work with class A. Of course, I could have a single class and annotate all additonal fields that won't be needed later with `@Transient`. But that would inflate my domain model class with a lot of fields that don't belong to it.

Comment: need more info. How does your Entity class A and B look like. Do you use spring-data-rest? If so then you can use `excerptProjection`. Did you look into `@Transient`

Comment: I don't think `excerptProjection` can help me here. `@Transient` would be a compromise, but not what I really want (see Edit).